# Syncronization block not working as expected, when aquired lock on required object, but works fine when applied on 'this'

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

```
public class SyncBlockIssue {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {    
            Thread r1= new Multi();
            Thread t1= new Thread(r1);          
            Thread t2= new Thread(r1);
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }
    }

    class Multi extends Thread
    {
        Integer count =new Integer(0);      
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
            {               
                    synchronized (count) {      
                    //synchronized (this) {   //working fine with this
                    count++;
                }               
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  "+count);          
        }       
    }
```

Above code is printing 2 million from 2nd thread, no matter how many times i run when acquire lock on 'this', but where as printing arbitrarily count, when acquired lock 'count' object.
could someone explain the difference.

Comment: General code style note: never pass a thread to another thread’s constructor. Your class `Multi` should not extend `Thread` but just implement `Runnable`. Smaller point: never use `new` when boxing a primitive type. Just `Integer count = 0;` will do. Starting with Java 9, you’ll get a warning when using `new Integer(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my guess, since I can't use comments to type so many words.

`Integer` objects are immutable:

```
    /**
     * The value of the {@code Integer}.
     *
     * @serial
     */
    private final int value;

    /**
     * Constructs a newly allocated {@code Integer} object that
     * represents the specified {@code int} value.
     *
     * @param   value   the value to be represented by the
     *                  {@code Integer} object.
     */
    public Integer(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
```

So, when you do `count++`, a new `Integer` object will be created. The `count` reference is then directed to the new object.

Assume the following flow:

1. `Thread r1` acquires `count` lock (Notice that the `count object` is locked), at this point `thread r2` is blocked.
2. `r1` invokes `count++`, a new `Integer` object is created. The `count` reference is then directed to the new object. And `r1` release lock.(This lock refers to the previous Integer object).
3. `r2`  which had been blocked acquires lock.
4. `r1` also acquires the lock because `count` has already pointed to a new object.
5. Both threads execute `count++`: problem arises.

The following code proves that both threads are holding the "lock" at the same time

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            synchronized (count) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "get lock");
                count++;
                if (i == 1) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "release lock");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note that when you have a construct like `synchronized (count) …`, the read of `count happens outside the `synchronized` block, before it can be entered. Therefore, there is no guaranty for a thread to see new vales written by another thread inside the `synchronized` block, as that guaranty only exists for code correctly synchronizing on the same object. So even if the second thread has not yet reached this point when the first does `count++`, it may still operate with the old object while the first proceeds with the new one.

Comment: There is also a data race which can lead to funky behavior.